# Nokogiri how to get an image that is not an icon?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I have created this method that parses a Wordpress XML for images.

```
 def get_image(doc, id)

    # Select all images in post
    images = Nokogiri::HTML(doc.xpath('//item')[id].xpath('content:encoded').text).xpath('//img')

    # Count number of images. 
    i = images.size

    if i == 0

      "No images found" 

    # We don't want icon images..
    elsif !images[0].attribute("src").to_s.scan("icon").empty?

      if i == 1
        "Only 1 picture that is icon - no image"
      else 

      t = 0

      #Loop all images and take the first that is not a smiley.
      loop do 
        t += 1
        images[t].attribute("src").to_s
        break if images[t].attribute("src").to_s.scan("icon").empty? || t > i
      end

      end 

    else

      images[0].attribute("src").to_s

    end

  end
```

This methods purpose is to get an image which is not an icon(smiley).

It takes  arguments doc which is a Nokogiri XML feed item(blog post) and ID which refers to the item number.

How do I create the loop in the method? I would like it to loop until there it has reached the total images in the post(i) or the attribute does not contain "icon".

Update solution inspired by okliv:

```
  def get_image(doc, id)

    images = Nokogiri::HTML(doc.xpath('//item')[id].xpath('content:encoded').text).xpath('//img')

    images_not_icons = images.collect{|image| image.attribute("src").to_s unless !image.attribute("src").to_s.scan("icon").empty?}.compact

    if images_not_icons.empty? || images_not_icons.nil?
      "no image"
    else
      images_not_icons.first
    end

  end
```

Comment: you can just add after `.compact` - `.try(:first).presence||"no image"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the start you have an array of all images in `images`, right?

Then collect only not icons like this:

```
images_not_icons = images.select{|image| image.attribute("src").to_s.scan("icon").empty?}
```

And then loop them:

```
images_not_icons.each do |image|
  image.do_something
end
```

Or, if I understood correctly that you just need `src` urls, then it is even easier:

```
images_not_icons.collect{|image| image.attribute("src").to_s}
```

You even can grab it in one row:

```
urls_of_images_not_icons = images.collect{|image| image.attribute("src").to_s unless image.attribute("src").to_s.scan("icon").empty?}.compact
```